# How to make Godot Camera2D not rotate along with the player?

Tags: rotation, godot

I have a simple side-scrolling platformer where the player is a ball, and I want him to rotate as he moves to look like he is rolling.

However, I have a 2D Camera set up so the player is at the bottom center of the screen. I want the player to stay there, but when I move the player the camera moves in circles along with the player.

How can I stop the camera from moving around?

Answer (score 1):

A few options come to mind:

- Presumably the player character is a `PhysicsBody2D` (e.g. a `KinematicBody2D`) with a `Sprite` or similar. And the `Camera2D` is a child of the `PhysicsBody2D`. Well, rotate the `Sprite`. That way the rotation does not affect the `Camera2D`. *Of course, if the rotation is driven by physics, then this option isn't helpful.*
- Well, there is no reason to make the `Camera2D` be a child of your `PhysicsBody2D` to make it follow it. Instead, you can use a `RemoteTransform2D` that pushes its position (with `update_position = true`), but not its rotation (with `update_rotation` = false) to another `Node2D`. And then you make your `Camera2D` a child that another `Node2D`.
- Let us say you don't want to have something as child of your character `PhysicsBody2D` at all. In that case, you can try a `PinJoint2D`. Set your `node_a` to the character `PhysicsBody2D`, and your `node_b` to some `RigidBody2D`, and then the `Camera2D` can be a child of the `RigidBody2D`.
- Or you can solve it with a script. You can add a `Node2D` and on its `_physics_process` you have it copy the `global_position` of your character to its own `global_position`, so that it follows it. Then make the `Camera2D` a child of the `Node2D`.